# Bootstrap 4 not working with Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just created a new Angular app in VS Code. I added Bootstrap 4 as per these directions:

https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

and changed the "styles" and "scripts" to add these lines (the jquery and popper lines were found in some other directions, I get the same error with or without those):

```
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
>   Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
>       at error (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>       at Function.browserslist.checkName (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
>       at Function.select (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
>       at D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at browserslist (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
>       at Browsers.parse (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
>       at new Browsers (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
>       at loadPrefixes (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
>       at plugin (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
>       at LazyResult.run (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:270:20)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:185:32)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:197:22)
>       at LazyResult.asyncTick (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:197:22)
>       at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (D:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\JobSolution\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:224:20)
>       at new Promise ()  @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 4:14-127  @ multi
>   ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

which of course I have no clue as to what that means. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). It is adapted to Angular and needs only the Bootstrap CSS, not the Javascript/jQuery code.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but that doesn't really answer my question. Not to mention that I want the full Bootstrap library and its abilities.

Comment: @StarfleetSecurity What gives you the impression that ng-bootstrap doesn't support all of Bootstrap 4's capabilities? Installing and loading jQuery in an Angular app just to support Bootstrap widgets seems pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an old tutorial you were following. Use this command to install Bootstrap 4:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 popper.js jquery --save
```

in angular-cli.json add these lines:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

**EDIT:**

**Internet Explorer For Bootstrap 4:**

Internet Explorer 10+ is supported; IE9 and down is not. Please be aware that some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements are not fully supported in IE10, or require prefixed properties for full functionality. Visit Can I use… for details on browser support of CSS3 and HTML5 features.

If you require IE8-9 support, use Bootstrap 3. It’s the most stable version of our code and is still supported by our team for critical bugfixes and documentation changes. However, no new features will be added to it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. However, I noticed that when I put a button my my HTML, like on the bootstrap example page, I don't get the "hand" cursor, it just stays as an arrow.

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>

Also, is there a reason you indicated to install the "alpha" version, rather than the latest "beta"?

Also, I noticed that if I use IE to navigate to the page, I don't see the button at all. But it appears okay in Chrome and Firefox (aside from the cursor issue mentioned above).

Comment: You're right! I made a mistake  You should use the beta version. I just test it it's working. I made the EDIT

Comment: This IE 11 I’m using, so I’m still not sure why the button isn’t showing. Also, why the cursor issue? Could these issues be related to using the alpha version?  Just saw your additional edit. I’ll try again with the latest beta when I get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: You're right! The beta 3 is causing the build to fail & the beta 2 is working but the hand cursor isn't showing

Comment: I reverted back to Bootstrap 3, but IE still isn't showing the button at all.

Comment: Is it just the button or it's not showing anything in IE?

Comment: All I have on the form is the button (to make sure Bootstrap was working). But apparently the problem isn't Bootstrap, as the button doesn't show in IE even without Bootstrap classes on it.

Comment: then you may want to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695280/ie-error-with-angular-2/46695592#46695592  It's for installing pollyfills

Comment: That worked, thanks. You'd think they'd make that a bit more obvious.

Comment: In your package json write     "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2", and then run npm install

Answer (score 0):

I used this command to install bootstrap version and with jquery and it worked for me. Hope it will work for you as well.

"npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 popper.js jquery --save"